# Popover the MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, uipopovercontroller

Am developing an ipad app in which I want to pop up the MPMoviePlayer controller in a required size(Say 3/4th of the screen). How it can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the MPMoviePlayerController view (it is not a UIViewController subclass but has a view property, which is a UIView), where ever you want (you can also set its frame as you wish)

```
moviePlayerController.view.frame = yourCustomFrame;
[otherView addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
```

> A movie player (of type MPMoviePlayerController) manages the playback
>   of a movie from a file or a network stream. Playback occurs in a view
>   owned by the movie player and takes place either fullscreen or inline.
>   You can incorporate a movie player’s view into a view hierarchy owned
>   by your app, or use an MPMoviePlayerViewController object to manage
>   the presentation for you.

EDIT:

To integrate it to a UIPopoverController, you can make a subclass of UIViewController, say YourVideoViewController which has a MPMoviePlayerController property (and adds the MPMoviePlayerController view to its own view), then create a UIPopoverController with YourVideoViewController.

EDIT:

You have MPMoviePlayerController synchronous

```
- (UIImage *)thumbnailImageAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)playbackTime timeOption:(MPMovieTimeOption)option
```

the movie must be loaded (you must register for the load state changes notifications), or asynchronous

```
- (void)requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:(NSArray *)playbackTimes timeOption:(MPMovieTimeOption)option
```

APIs. In the latter case you should register for `MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification` notifications to get the thumbnails.

Comment: Can it be integrated with popupviewcontroller so that the video can be popped out when play button is pressed?

Comment: Edited in response to your comment.

Comment: Hey thanks. Is it possible to extract the thumbnail \ first frame of the video through objective - c?

Comment: Edited in response to comment, you should ask separate questions for separate problems.

Comment: I want to extract only the first thumbnail of the video and make it as a background image for a button. By clicking on the button the video needs to be popped up and played